# Is it safe to put a 8-lane PCI Express 3.0 card into a 16-lane PCI Express 2.0 slot?

Tags: compatibility, pci-express

Title says it.

I have a [Dell Perc H330](https://i.dell.com/sites/doccontent/shared-content/data-sheets/en/Documents/Dell-PowerEdge-RAID-Controller-H330.pdf) and would like to put it into a mainboard that has a PCI-express 2.0 16x slot. Is this compatible?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is safe.

PCI-E slots are designed to be backward compatible.

You will only get 2.0 speeds.

I have x8 adaptec controller in a x16 slot for years.